# Food safety concern - storing medium rare steak overnight

Tags: food-safety, steak, storage, culinary-uses

I hope this is an ok first question to ask. So, yesterday my partner and I had steaks at a pub, and he saved half of his medium rare one. We came home and put it in the fridge, but he decided to leave it overnight and cook it into pilaf this evening. I was ... sort of horrified about it to be honest, but he seems to think it's completely fine. It's now cooked through and not rare anymore, he boiled it in the pilaf for a good amount of time. Still, I'm convinced this is pretty bad practice and I'm worried he'll get food poisoning. Thoughts?

Comment: Sorry to close your first question immediately, but food safety rules are more literal than people think. Second guessing what is different when you eat rare steak or whatever is counterproductive. Please read the related question and maybe also our standard info on food safety if you don't know the basics, https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/food-safety/info

Comment: I do this sort of thing all the time with steaks that I've prepared at home.  The main question is going to be  how long it took the steak to get home from when it was served 'til when it was chilled back down.  (my mom called these 'planned overs' ... making a little too much food the first night so she could turn it into a different meal the next night)

Comment: Perhaps I must read the food safety link too. But what could have been different if the steak was uncooked raw , taken from a butcher, put in the fridge and coiked into a pilaf the day adter? These are the concerns that I dont really get. .....